# Simultaneous Arraylists

Tags: java, android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SQLiteHelper> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SQLiteHelper>()
                .setQuery(mFetchingMessages, SQLiteHelper.class)
                .build();

final MainData mHelper = new MainData(this);
final Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions3();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SQLiteHelper, Chat.MessagesViewHolder>(options) {

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Chat.MessagesViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final SQLiteHelper model) {

        final DatabaseReference mTimeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
        Query messageQuery = mTimeReference.limitToLast(10);

        messageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    SQLiteHelper message = dataSnapshot.getValue(SQLiteHelper.class);


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });



                    messages.add(message);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

 @Override
    public Chat.MessagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_chat, parent, false);
        return new Chat.MessagesViewHolder(view);
    }
};
messageList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

SQLite

```
while (csr.moveToNext()) {
    String mSender = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SENDER));
    String mMessage = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE));
    long mTime = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME));
    String mSeen = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEEN));
    String mTimer = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMER));
    String mType = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));

    messages.add(new SQLiteHelper(mSender, mMessage, mType, mSeen, mTimer, mTime));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When i have both only the firebase data is shown and when i remove or comment the firebase part of code the sqlite part of code is shown in recyclerview. Can someone suggest me to make the firebase code show below the sqlite code somehow please?

Comment: Please post a little more context and format it to make it more readable because I suspect that we won't be able to help you with the current information.

Comment: I just want to know how do you add 2 arraylists to one recyclerview @JosepOriolSolerCatalà